# Correct way to calculate best camera preview size maintaing aspect ratio

Tags: java, android, android-camera, aspect-ratio, cwac-camera

**QUESTION**

How do you programmatically *and accurately* determine the best preview size for an application that is displaying the camera's preview at the device's screen size? (Or inside any view of variable dimensions, really).

**BEFORE YOU TRY TO MARK THIS AS A DUPLICATE OF ONE OF THE MILLIONS OF OTHER ASPECT RATIO RELATED QUESTIONS ON SO please understand that I am searching for a different solution than what is generally available**.  I ask this question because I have read so many "answers" but they all point to a solution that I feel is incomplete (and potentially flawed as I will describe here). If it's not a flaw then please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

I have read a lot of different implementations on how applications choose preview sizes and most of them take an approach that I am calling the "close enough" approach (where you decide which option is best based on subtracting the ratio of the size option from the ratio of the screen resolution and find the option with the lowest value).  This approach seems to not ensure that it is picking the *best option* but ensure that it won't pick the *worst option*.

For example if I try to iterate through each available preview size on a device with screen resolution of `720x1184` and display the preview full screen (`720x1184`) here are the results of the camera preview (sorted by options that are closest to the screen resolution in the format `abs(ratio of size option - screen resolution ratio)` ).  All sizes come from [.getSupportedPreviewSizes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes())).  ("Results" are from visual observations using a test case using a static circle that appears in the camera's viewfinder and are not programmatic)

```
720.0/1184.0 = 0.6081081081081081

Res         Ratio         Delta in ratios  Result       
----------------------------------------------------   
176/144   = 1.22222222222 (0.614114114114) (vertically stretched)
352/288   = 1.22222222222 (0.614114114114) (vertically stretched)
320/240   = 1.33333333333 (0.725225225225) (vertically stretched)
640/480   = 1.33333333333 (0.725225225225) (vertically stretched)
720/480   = 1.5           (0.891891891892) (vertically stretched)
800/480   = 1.66666666667 (1.05855855856)  (looks good)
640/360   = 1.77777777778 (1.16966966967)  (horizontally squashed)
1280/720  = 1.77777777778 (1.16966966967)  (slight horizontal squash)
1920/1080 = 1.77777777778 (1.16966966967)  (slight horizontal squash)
```

It wouldn't be a proper Android code test without running it on another device.  Here are the results of displaying a camera preview on a device with screen resolution 800x1216 and displaying the preview at the same resolution (`800x1216`)

```
800/1216.0 = 0.657894736842

Res         Ratio         Delta in ratios  Results
------------------------------------------------
176/144   = 1.22222222222 (0.56432748538)  (looks vertically stretched)
352/288   = 1.22222222222 (0.56432748538)  (looks vertically stretched)
480/368   = 1.30434782609 (0.646453089245) (looks vertically stretched)
320/240   = 1.33333333333 (0.675438596491) (looks vertically stretched)
640/480   = 1.33333333333 (0.675438596491) (looks vertically stretched)
800/600   = 1.33333333333 (0.675438596491) (looks vertically stretched)
480/320   = 1.5           (0.842105263158) (looks good)
720/480   = 1.5           (0.842105263158) (looks good)
800/480   = 1.66666666667 (1.00877192982)  (looks horizontally squashed)
960/540   = 1.77777777778 (1.11988304094)  (looks horizontally squashed)
1280/720  = 1.77777777778 (1.11988304094)  (looks horizontally squashed)
1920/1080 = 1.77777777778 (1.11988304094)  (looks horizontally squashed)
864/480   = 1.8           (1.14210526316)  (looks horizontally squashed)
```

The "close enough" approach (assuming that any delta in ratio is equal to or less than `1.4d` is acceptable) would return `1920x1080` on both devices if iterating through lowest to highest values.  If iterating through highest to lowest values it would pick `176x144` for DeviceA and `176x144` for DeviceB.  Both of those options (although "close enough") are not the best options.

**QUESTION**

In studying the results above how can I programatically derive the values that "look good"?  I can't get these values with the "close enough" approach so I am misunderstanding the relationship between screen size, view that I am displaying the preview in and the preview sizes themselves. What am I missing?

```
           Screen dimensions      = 720x1184
             View dimensions      = 720x1184
Screen and View Aspect Ratio      = 0.6081081081081081
Best Preview Size ratio (720x480) = 1.5
```

Why are the best options not the values that have the lowest delta in ratios?
The results are surprising since everyone else seems to think the best option is by calculating the smallest difference in ratios but what I'm seeing is that the best option seems to be in the middle of all of the options.  And that their width is closer to the width of the view that will display the preview.

Based on the above observations (that the best option is not the value with the lowest delta in ratios) I have developed this algorithm that iterates though all of the possible preview sizes, checks if it meets my "close enough" criteria , stores the sizes that meet this criteria and finally find the value that is at least greater than or equal to provided width.

```
public static Size getBestAspectPreviewSize(int displayOrientation,
                                            int width,
                                            int height,
                                            Camera.Parameters parameters,
                                            double closeEnough) {


    double targetRatio=(double)width / height;
    Size bestSize = null;

    if (displayOrientation == 90 || displayOrientation == 270) {
        targetRatio=(double)height / width;
    }

    List<Size> sizes=parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    TreeMap<Double, List> diffs = new TreeMap<Double, List>();


    for (Size size : sizes) {

        double ratio=(double)size.width / size.height;

        double diff = Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio);
        if (diff < closeEnough){
            if (diffs.keySet().contains(diff)){
                //add the value to the list
                diffs.get(diff).add(size);
            } else {
                List newList = new ArrayList<Camera.Size>();
                newList.add(size);
                diffs.put(diff, newList);
            }

            Logging.format("usable: %sx%s %s", size.width, size.height, diff);
        }
    }

    //diffs now contains all of the usable sizes
    //now let's see which one has the least amount of
    for (Map.Entry entry: diffs.entrySet()){
        List<Size> entries = (List)entry.getValue();
        for (Camera.Size s: entries) {

            if (s.width >= width && s.height >= width) {
                bestSize = s;
            }
            Logging.format("results: %s %sx%s", entry.getKey(), s.width, s.height);
        }
    }

    //if we don't have bestSize then just use whatever the default was to begin with
    if (bestSize==null){
        if (parameters.getPreviewSize()!=null){
            bestSize = parameters.getPreviewSize();
            return bestSize;
        }

        //pick the smallest difference in ratio?  or pick the largest resolution?
        //right now we are just picking the lowest ratio difference
        for (Map.Entry entry: diffs.entrySet()){
            List<Size> entries = (List)entry.getValue();
            for (Camera.Size s: entries) {
                if (bestSize == null){
                    bestSize = s;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bestSize;
}
```

Obviously this algorithm doesn't know how to pick the best option just knows how to pick an option that is not the worst like every other implementation I have seen out there.  I need to understand the relationship between the sizes that actually look good and the view dimensions that the preview will be displayed in before I can improve my algorithm to actually pick the best option.

I have looked at the implementation of how [CommonWares' camera-cwac](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/camera/src/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/CameraUtils.java#L28) project deals with this and it appears to also use the "close enough" algorithm.  If I apply that same logic to my project then I get back values that are decent but not the "perfect" size.  I get `1920x1080` back for both devices.  Although that value is not the worst option it's also slightly squished.  I am going to run his code in my test app with test cases to determine if it also squishes the image slightly since I already know that it will return a size that isn't as optimal as it could be.

Comment: I think you need to recalculate your display ratios and then the deltas, since the display is in portrait mode.

Answer (score 4):

> Why are the best options not the values that have the lowest delta in ratios?

#### They are! But you need to calculate your screen ratios according to your current screen orientation! :)

So, since your device is in landscape mode, the first table should look like this :

```
1184.0/720.0 = 1.6444444

Res         Ratio         Delta in ratios  Result       
----------------------------------------------------   
176/144   = 1.222 ( 0.422) (vertically stretched)
352/288   = 1.222 ( 0.422) (vertically stretched)
320/240   = 1.333 ( 0.311) (vertically stretched)
640/480   = 1.333 ( 0.311) (vertically stretched)
720/480   = 1.500 ( 0.144) (vertically stretched)
800/480   = 1.666 (-0.016) (looks good)
640/360   = 1.777 (-0.126) (horizontally squashed)
1280/720  = 1.777 (-0.126) (slight horizontal squash)
1920/1080 = 1.777 (-0.126) (slight horizontal squash)
```

See? The smallest **absolute** delta is your **best choice**.

Comment: Well look at that! :D  So is landscape mode the default mode for all devices or is this something that I can query the device for?

Comment: I wouldn't know about that. I am pretty confident it is __not default__ for all devices. You can definitely query the device for orientation.

Comment: Well, you should ABS the delta value. You care about if it's the difference is smaller.

Comment: `getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();` This is how to get the screen orientation in runtime.

Comment: you can query for orientation but that will just give you the current orientation (if the user is holding it in portrait or landscape mode) and not the value that should determine if I should calculate my ratios based on w/h or h/w.

Comment: Landscape / Portrait mode is more complicated, some tablets (Samsung,...) have default mode Portrait (like a phone), some (Nexus7-1Gen, Nexus10) had default landscape. The Github sample I  mentioned deals with the issue here: https://github.com/seanpjanson/AndyCam/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/andycam/Util.java#L53.  Also the preview size in 'surfaceChanged()' comes in landscape:  https://github.com/seanpjanson/AndyCam/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/andycam/CamVw.java#L56, so you must pre-rotate the view and post-rotate the picture.

Comment: In general the landscape / portrait issue on tablets can be figured out from the difference between display size (wide/tall) and tablet's rotation at any given moment. What a mess.

Answer (score 1):

You will never get ratio that 'fits perfect'. The surface on different devices will change by presence of other screen items (title bar, rotation, ...). You have to pick the closest ratio and position the preview on the screen so it either overflows on sides or leaves (black) strips on the sides (center it). Look at this [GitHub exercise](https://github.com/seanpjanson/AndyCam) where I tried to tackle the problem. The best you can do is to let the preview 'overflow' the display surface.

Also, the picture you get after 'takePicture' has again different size and ratio. There is a way to 'crop' the resulting picture to the ratio of the preview, if that is what you want (the example I mention does it differently). Still, the problem you are trying to tackle can not be solved perfectly. For instance, if your surface area is 1000x800 and your closest available preview ratio is 1200x800, you have to select that one and set ['fit-in' here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/AndyCam/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/andycam/Util.java#L41) to false. Now you'll see cropped portion of selected preview size (100pixs overflowing on each size, but who cares, it is not visible).

When you get the picture later, again, you have to select he size that suits your needs. Not only the closest ratio, but also the picture size itself. For instance if you got picture size 2000x1500 (as you chose) and you want to keep only the portion visible on the screen, you have to crop it to the 1000x800 ratio of your surface (5:4), resulting in picture 1875x1500. Or, for instance, if you're low on memory and use the picture for upload/viewing, you may shoot for smaller pic size like 800x600 and crop it to 750x600.

Be careful, though, the GitHub example I mentioned goes the other way, it tries to get the final picture of desired size 1600x1200 (ratio 4:3).

I hope I got close enough to help you with something that cannot be answered with simple yes/no. Just the fact that Camera API has so many questions here indicates that the solution is not clean.

Comment: Overflowing the bounds of the view seems like a good way to go since there will be no distortion in the image - the only tricky part would be in cropping the final image.  In my scenario I have a square `FrameLayout` that acts as a "mask" that will only let a square portion of the Camera's `SurfaceView` be visible to the user (think Instagram camera view).  It will always be a square so the final image will be `screenWidth x screenWidth` in dimension. Can you point me in the right direction in how to go about cropping out the image assuming both my preview size and picture size are different?

Comment: So I will always display my preview at the device's full resolution but the user will only see a square portion of that.

Comment: @MaxWorg Assuming you are running Android Studio, try to pull the GitHub example (I believe FIT_IN is set 'true'), select the preview that is 1:1 (hopefuly the camera has one) and play with this code section:  https://github.com/seanpjanson/AndyCam/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/andycam/CamVw.java#L54

Comment: If you don't find ratio 1.000, select the closest one and mask the surface with a square template (FrameLayout that contains SurfaceView + Imageview with square transparent opening). Sorry I can't help more, busy with completely unrelated Android issues.